# How to keep Schema Properties ordered with AWS::ApiGateway::Model CloudFormation

Tags: model, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation to define my API. Once I added the Model resource (AWS::ApiGateway::Model) and updated the stack, Properties order has changed, is there a way to force CF to respect the order defined in the resource? See how Properties order differ from CF template to Console after stack update, Thank you.

Template:

```
PortsArrayModel:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Model
Properties:
  RestApiId: !Ref BWTAPI
  ContentType: application/json
  Description: Schema for Ports example
  Name: PortsArray
  Schema:
    $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#'
    title: 'Ports array'
    type: array
    items:
      type: object
      properties:
        Port_ID:
          type: integer
        Port_Name:
          type: string
        Province:
          type: string
        Lat_Actual:
          type: integer
        Long_Actual:
          type: integer
        Lat_Origin:
          type: integer
        Long_Origin:
          type: integer
```

API Gateway console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

YAML CFN templates are always converted to JSON when they are executed (YAML is just a less verbose way to define JSON). However, the JSON specification clearly states that ["An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) meaning that there is no way to enforce this and that if this happens, it must be regarded as an implementation detail and cannot be relied upon as the implementation can change while still conforming to the specification.